# PNG icons windows universal xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have several images with the png extension in my project where in android and ios they appear correct, already in universal windows they do not appear. I made the test the following I changed one of the images to jpg and funcionol, appeared my image in universal windows. Will I have to change all the images? Or do you have a way to solve this so that my images will be PNG?

An example of how I call the pictures ...

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="facebook.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"/>
                <Image Source="twitter.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"/>
                <Image Source="whatsapp.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely URI resolution fails, you should really follow [documentation's guidelines](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images) when it comes to working with embedded images.